# Return last row if there exists data in the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a function which will check if the already existing sheet is new or has data. If it consists data then it should return the last row, else it must return the first row. I am using the following code:

```
Private Function GetLastRow(sheetName As String) As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).End(xlUp).Row

GetLastRow = lastRow
End Function
```

But on debugging, I get an error that says that there is no object set. 
Is there any error in my code?

Comment: What is `CurrentWorkbook`, and what if a sheet contains more rows than an Integer can hold? Here is a reference to a more complete [function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95019/75176)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub TEST()
    Debug.Print GetLastRow(ActiveSheet.Name)
End Sub

Private Function GetLastRow(ByVal sheetName As String) As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        On Error GoTo returnVal
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
    GetLastRow = lastRow
    
Exit Function
returnVal:
    GetLastRow = 1
End Function
```

Comment: If you find the last populated row then use .End(xlUp), you'll likely end up on the first row.

Comment: On debugging, xlUp = -4162, is it of any significance??

Comment: @Jeeped Well spotted.

Comment: @NimyAlex no, the -4162 is just the actual value of the `xlUp` variable defined by the [XlDirection Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xldirection-enumeration-excel)

Answer (score 1):

With these functions you can always find the last row and last column, you can feed sheet you are looking for the last row or last column and more importantly you can use which column or row is the criterion for you. If you omit the arguments, it will use the active sheet as the worksheet and it will use the first column to find the last row/cell and fist row to find the last column/cell

```
Function LastRowInColumn(Optional sh As Worksheet, Optional colNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    'Finds the last row in a particular column which has a value in it
    If sh Is Nothing Then
        Set sh = ActiveSheet
    End If
    LastRowInColumn = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, colNumber).End(xlUp).row
End Function

Function LastColumnInRow(Optional sh As Worksheet, Optional rowNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    'Finds the last column in a particular row which has a value in it
    If sh Is Nothing Then
            Set sh = ActiveSheet
        End If
    LastColumnInRow = sh.Cells(rowNumber, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one I use:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal arg_ws As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim rTest As Range

    Set rTest = arg_ws.Cells.Find("*", arg_ws.Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlPrevious)
    If Not rTest Is Nothing Then GetLastRow = rTest.Row Else GetLastRow = 0

End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Sub tst()

    MsgBox GetLastRow(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference the parent worksheet completely and use a long, not an integer. The end(xlup) was superfluous.

```
Private Function GetLastRow(sheetName As String) As Long
    Dim lastRow As long

    with ActiveWorkbook.workSheets(sheetName)
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
    end with
    GetLastRow = lastRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function LastRow(Optional SpecificCol, Optional TargetShtName) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, temp_LRow, LRow As Long
    
    If IsMissing(TargetShtName) Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = Sheets(TargetShtName)
    End If

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        temp_LRow = Split(Split(.UsedRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(2) + 0
        If Err Then GoTo emptysht:
        
        For LRow = temp_LRow To 1 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.rows(LRow)) <> 0 Then
                If IsMissing(SpecificCol) Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells(LRow, columns(SpecificCol).Column)) <> 0 Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next LRow
        
        If LRow = 0 Then
emptysht:   Err.Clear
            LRow = 1
        End If
        
        LastRow = LRow
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).